Create area clusters in QGIS based on the sum of a field using the modeler
I want to cluster a point layer so that the internal sum of a numeric column (in this case, 'ebw_totale') within each cluster does not exceed 220. How can I do this with the modeler in QGIS?



Which methods/tools have you used so far? What were the results? What are you prerequisites for your clustering?

@Fjedsen I haven’t been able to do it yet, so I haven’t used any tools or methods so far. The result I would like is multiple polygons, each containing several points, where the sum of the points within each polygon does not exceed 220.

Okay, I think you need to figure out the rules, how the algorithm should cluster points. Because there is not one single solution to this problem. I think you need to do some research on CrossValidated: https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=clustering+algorithm

@Fjedsen I have already done research on similar topics, but I haven't found any that match my request exactly.

I think the standard tools in the Toolbox do not offer a technical solution to your problem. A better way would be to approach this with other software, e.g. Python.
